# Bridged KVM guest crashes other guests on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04

Tags: 20.04, windows, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I am new to Ubuntu, but am running Desktop 20.04.  I have installed KVM and configured bridged networking per the following two links based on my understanding that the legacy networking service has been replaced by NetworkManager and netplan:
[Creating an ubuntu kvm networked bridge interface](https://www.answertopia.com/ubuntu/creating-an-ubuntu-kvm-networked-bridge-interface/) , [How to setup bridge networking with kvm on ubuntu](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-setup-bridge-networking-with-kvm-on-ubuntu-20-04-9c560b3e3991).

I am able to bridge my windows guest and it starts and runs with complete local network and internet connectivity.  But when I start another windows guest, it crashes the first.  And vice versa.  Both are configured to use the host-bridge with a static IP.

My `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` file contains:
[image]

And the `ip addr` output confirms the bridge is working correctly:
[image]

And `networkctl list` output is:
[image]

And `brctl list` output is:
[image]

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciate.
Thank you.

Comment: You haven't specified a renderer in your .yaml file. I have seen other comments that it matters. Your IPs and MACs are different for each windows guest, correct?

Comment: Yes, the IPs and MACs are unique for each guest.  And I addded 'renderer:  networkd' to the file, and restarted the systemd-networkd service.  But the problem still persists.

Comment: Everything looks O.K. to me. As a test, I am running 3 VMs under 20.04, with bridged networking right now. I had a very very difficult time getting this working in early May. [My problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333453/bridged-networking-in-kvm-qemu-lan-addressed-packets-dropped) turned out to be that my processor was too new for 20.04, and I had to enable HWE so as to have a newer kernel. The only significant difference I see between us, is that I have STP turned off.

Comment: That is interesting.  I had a "forced upgrade" as well as I damaged the old processor when upgrading the case & motherboard.  I'm now running a Ryzen 7 5800x, which was released recently.  So I wonder if there is an incompatibility with Ubuntu 20.04 desktop.  Anyway, thank you for taking the time to look at the issue, @DougSmythies .