# modprobe intel_rapl_common: no such device on Intel Core 11th-i7 dual-boot system

Tags: 18.04, kernel, power-management, interface, intel-cpu

I am using a Dual-boot laptop (Windows10 and Ubuntu18.04 LTS), and I am trying to using the Intel RAPL interface for power measurement in Ubuntu. When I want to use `sudo modprobe intel_rapl_common` to load the kernel module, the error messages returns "No such device". Also, the following two folders   "/sys/devices/virtual/powercap/" and "/sys/class/powercap/" are empty which should be the place where intel_rapl is located. To the best of my knowledge, RAPL has been integrated into Intel's Sandy Bridge and I have seen power measurement on 11th i7, can anyone help with this issue?

Additional information:

1. tried `sudo depmod` then `modprobe`, same error.
2. `uname -r`: 5.4.0-107-generic
3. `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name *rapl*` output:

````
/lib/modules/5.4.0-107-generic/kernel/arch/x86/events/rapl.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-107-generic/kernel/drivers/powercap/intel_rapl_msr.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-107-generic/kernel/drivers/powercap/intel_rapl_common.ko```
````

Comment: As far as I know, the modules load by default. do you get any insight from `sudo dmesg | grep -i rapl`?

Comment: There is no rapl detected. I wonder whether this is issue is related in the folowing: When I open Software & Update -> Additional Driver, the GUI displayes Intel Corporation Unknown -> Do no use this device (in gray text). I searched online but it seems to be a wifi driver issue (though my wifi connection is fine), but not related to RAPL.

Comment: With a 10th gen Intel processor, and for [a different reason](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333453/bridged-networking-in-kvm-qemu-lan-addressed-packets-dropped/1336971#1336971), I found the 5.4 series kernel was not new enough, and had to go to HWE on my 20.04 test server.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading kernel to 5.6, the issue is solved.