# KVM VM not ping to host and gateway ip on bridge mode

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, ethernet, kvm-virtualization

## Linux Version

"Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-122-generic x86_64)"

## KVM Version

Package: qemu-system-x86
Version: 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.23
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Source: qemu
Origin: Ubuntu

## Network Configuration on host machine

```
network:  
  version: 2  
  renderer: networkd  
  
  ethernets:  
    enp0s31f6:  
      dhcp4: false  
      dhcp6: false  
  bridges:  
    br0:  
      interfaces: [enp0s31f6]  
      addresses: [x.x.28.243/32]  
      routes:  
        - on-link: true  
          to: 0.0.0.0/0  
          via: x.x.28.193  
      gateway6: fe80::1  
      parameters:  
        stp: false  
        forward-delay: 0  
      dhcp4: no  
      dhcp6: no  
  version: 2
```

## IP Add on host machine

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00  
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:1b:0e:fa:70:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s31f6.4002@enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:1b:0e:fa:70:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.9.209/24 brd 192.168.9.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s31f6.4002
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9477:6a8c:e1b6:b3a7/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.110.1/24 brd 192.168.110.255 scope global noprefixroute virbr2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::40ca:cfff:fe2e:76c2/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:c5:79:5e:ef:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global noprefixroute virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c5:79ff:fe5e:efc5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: virbr1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:4a:eb:65 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global virbr1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: virbr1-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr1 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:4a:eb:65 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:1b:0e:fa:70:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet x.x.28.243/32 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3087:19ff:fe98:e699/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:02:37:3b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe02:373b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

## KVM VM

IP Address x.x.28.247/26
gateway x.x.28.193

VM can ping only its own IP(x.x.28.247). but can't ping to host IP (x.x.28.193) and its gateway (x.x.28.193). on the other hand host machine can ping gateway ip(x.x.28.193) but not to VM IP (x.x.28.247).

Comment: What is your host processor make and model? I have had troubles with VMs using bridges with 5.4 series kernels with newer Intel processors. I had to enable HWE stack which included moving to 5.13 series kernels. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333453/bridged-networking-in-kvm-qemu-lan-addressed-packets-dropped).

Comment: cat /proc/cpuinfo  
processor       : 0  
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel  
cpu family      : 6  
model           : 158  
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz  
stepping        : 9    
microcode       : 0xf0    
cpu MHz         : 800.638  
cache size      : 8192 KB  
physical id     : 0  
siblings        : 8  
core id         : 0  
cpu cores       : 4  
apicid          : 0  
initial apicid  : 0  
fpu             : yes  
fpu_exception   : yes  
cpuid level     : 22  
wp              : yes  
# Model

Comment: #  Model 
FUJITSU D3401-H2

Comment: I don't fully understand why you have so many virbr's or if your vnet0 is properly bridged to br0. Review this [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412503/setting-up-a-bridge-for-host-and-vm). Isn't your host address X.X.28.243, not X.X.28.193?